# Access a method from another method within same class - android

Tags: java, android

In a Class `MyClass`,
I have a method

```
public static void myMethod1(Context context, ClassA a, final ClassB.CompletedTaskListener completedListener) throws JSONException, SQLException {
```

I need to access the above method inside the below method of the same class,

```
private static void myMethod2(final MyClass myclass) throws JSONException { 
    User currentUser = MainActivity.getUser();
    final HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    params.put("username", myclass.getUsername());
    params.put("data", CommonUtils.toJsonString(myclass.toMap()));
    try {
        HttpClientUtils.postSignedRequestWithCallback(URL, params,
            APISignatureType.SIG_COMPLEX, 
            new HttpClientUtils.CustomCallbackListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                    myclass.setSaved(true);
                    myclass.setStatus(AppStatus.STATUS_SUBMITTED);
                    //Here I use the myMethod1 which shows error
                    myclass.myMethod1(context,user,completedOneDownloadTaskListener);
                }
                @Override
                public void onFailure(int statusCode) {
                }
            });
    }catch (Exception e){
    }
}
```

When i use `myMethod1(context,a,completedListener);` inside the `myMethod2` I get compilation error.

I get error as,

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'completedListener' 
Cannot resolve symbol 'a'
Non-static field 'context' cannot be referenced from a static context Static member 'com.mypack.model.MyClass.myMethod(android.content.Context, com.mypack.model.ClassA, com.mypack.service.ClassB.CompletedTaskListener)' accessed via instance reference
```

Comment: what error .............?

Comment: I think we will either need more details or the full source of `myMethod2` to answer this question.

Comment: @emerssso Sure, I will update the entire code

Comment: @emerssso Updated the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`context`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/content/Context.html) is not a static value, but rather an object.

Either remove the `static` modifier from your methods, or dont use `context` inside them

Comment: Thank you so much. Removing static helped me get rid of the error, However the values inside the `myMethod2` for `myclass.myMethod1(context,user,completedOneDownloadTaskListener);` get null values.

Comment: Edit your question, post the logcat with the error, as well as a description on the task you are doing. I have not seen a reason for your class to have a Class as an argument

Answer (score 0):

In complement to Bonatti answer I suggest to put an other parameter in your `method2` so you can still use your static methods since context is not accessed via instance reference.

```
private static void myMethod2(final MyClass myclass, Context context) throws JSONException
```